# Could someone help me understand how this works?

Tags: c

This is a from an old homework exercise that I'm trying to solve. It asks to describe the process and explain the result (it prints out `1,0,1,1`). I'm having a really hard time figuring things out. Could someone provide me with an explanation?

```
int main() {
    int i = 4, j = -1, k = 0, w, x, y, z;

    w = i || j || k;
    x = i && k && k;
    y = i || j && k;
    z = i && j || k;
    printf("%d,%d,%d,%d\n", w, x, y, z);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you know all of the operators used? If yes, do you know in what order they are applied? Knowing how much you know will make explaining easier.

Comment: @lucidbrot yes I'm aware of what the operators mean, and I believe they are applied from left to right,right? I just cant figure out why 4 || -1 gives back  1 for example.

Comment: @vmp thank you so much. I wasn't aware of how C treats 1s and 0s. This cleared everything up for me .Thanks!

Comment: @philipnasus: No, they are not always applied from left to right. The `&&` has precedence over `||`. See [this table](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) for further information.

Answer (score 3):

1. C treats 0 as false and any other value as true.

`&&` has higher precedence than `||`, hence `y= i || j && k;` is equivalent to `y = i || (j && k);` (simmilar to what happens with `+` and `*`.

Having all that and a truth table for `AND (&&)` and `OR (||)` operations you can just consider the info in `1.` and compare to the table.

Answer (score 1):

Making operator associativity and precedence explicit and applying the values gives:

- `w = i || j || k;` -> `w = (i || j) || k;` -> `w = (4 || j) || k` -> `w = (1 || j) || k` -> `1 || k` -> `w = 1`
- `x = i && k && k;` -> `x = (i && j) && k;` -> `x = (4 && -1) && k` -> `x = (1 && 1) && k` -> `x = 1 && k` -> `x = 1 && 0` -> `x = 0`
- `y = i || j && k;` -> `y = i || (j && k);` -> `y = 4 || (j && k);` -> `y = 1 || (j && k);` -> `y = 1`
- `z = i && j || k;` -> `z = (i && j) || k;` -> `z = (4 && j) || k;` -> `z = (1 && -1) || k;` -> `z = 1 || k;` -> `z = 1`